# How can I make a button redirect my page to another page (depending on the input)

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, button, authentication

I created following Loginpage
code.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login Form</title>
        <style>
        .login-form {
            width: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
        }
        .login-form h1 {
            text-align: center;
            color: #4d4d4d;
            font-size: 24px;
            padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
        }
        .login-form input[type="password"],
        .login-form input[type="text"] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 15px;
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            box-sizing:border-box;
        }
        .login-form input[type="submit"] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 15px;
            background-color: #535b63;
            border: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="login-form">
            <h1>Please enter a password:</h1>
            <form action="auth" method="POST">

                <form action="google.com">
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                </form>

<form action="http://google.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Depending on the Input of the Passwort, i want to redirect to another page. So if somebody write "1111" he should land on google. If someone write "1234" he should land on youtube and if someone write none of these both, then he should stay at the page and get an error message. For example : "wrong pw"

Comment: you need only one input, based on the input value you can redirect. no need to create new form for each input.

Comment: how do I do it ? redirect based on the input value? can you send a example code please?

Comment: You probably want to use a normal button instead of a submit button. And then https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event followed by https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location . Keep in mind that unless you store the valid passwords on the server, I will just look up the correct one in the code.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this. You have a mess of forms on the page. You might want to study up on web form to better understand the issue. Here is one way to do what you want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login Form</title>
        <style>
        .login-form {
            width: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
        }
        .login-form h1 {
            text-align: center;
            color: #4d4d4d;
            font-size: 24px;
            padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
        }
        .login-form input[type="password"],
        .login-form input[type="text"] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 15px;
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            box-sizing:border-box;
        }
        .login-form input[type="submit"] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 15px;
            background-color: #535b63;
            border: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="login-form">
            <h1>Please enter a password:</h1>
            <form>
                <input id="passwordTextbox" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Send" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event){
                document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var value = document.getElementById('passwordTextbox').value;
                    if (value=='1111') {
                        window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
                    } else if (value=='1234') {
                        window.location.href = 'https://www.youtube.com';
                    } else {
                        // show error
                        alert('Password is invalid');
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can do something like below**

```js
$(document).on('click', '#send', function(e) {

var values = $('#password').val();

if(values == 1111) {
  location ="google.com";
}

} )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login Form</title>
        <style>
        .login-form {
            width: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
        }
        .login-form h1 {
            text-align: center;
            color: #4d4d4d;
            font-size: 24px;
            padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
        }
        .login-form input[type="password"],
        .login-form input[type="text"] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 15px;
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            box-sizing:border-box;
        }
        .login-form input[type="submit"] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 15px;
            background-color: #535b63;
            border: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="login-form">
            <h1>Please enter a password:</h1>
            <form action="auth" method="POST">

        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <input type="button" id="send" value="Send" />
              


            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do by adding event listener onchange o onclick to your input,please refer to given jsfiddle

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/ce09xgt1/1/`
```